# NpgsqlException is not caught in catch block

Tags: c#, postgresql, exception, npgsql

I am connecting to local postgresql instance like this:

```
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("loadProjects", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    connection.Open();

                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NpgsqlException ex)
        {
           ...
        }
```

Then for testing purposes I stop database server from Task Manager=>Services and when I try to connect of course get exception : *"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
"* But interesting part is that this exception is not caught by the catch block but simply crashes my program at line connection.Open(). Can anyone explain, why is it so?

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual exception thrown? Change the code to `catch(Exception ex)` and rerun it and take a look at the actual type.

Comment: "Can anyone explain, why is it so?" the simplest explanation would be that a `NpgsqlException` is not thrown, but one from another type

Comment: I've seen a lot of cases where the using handles the exception.  Put two exception handler inside the using and see if you capture the exception.

Comment: @Sean I changed code to catch(Exception ex) and what I get is "Message = No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" and "Source = Npgsql" Shouldn't exceptions of this type be catched by NpgsqlException?

Comment: See if you can connect to that server on the same machine your code is running through a normal SQL IDE (PgAdmin or whatever).  I suspect the issue is on the server

Comment: @niks - You shouldn't assume that's the type of exception thrown, even if it sounds like it should be. When you run the changed code you should be able to see what the type is in the debugger.

Comment: looking at the [souce code on git hub of the connector class](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnector.cs) there are 15 cases where this `NpgsqlException` exception is thrown, and none of them cary this error message of "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Comment: Oh, yes, it is "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"

Comment: that was also my assumption . The connector class has a Socket field => `Socket _socket = default!;` which basically establishes the connection. This throws the exception. You should always have as last catch a general `catch(Exception ex)` clause, because you never know from how deep the exception might come. And the documentation will not tell you all the exceptions that it might throw :)

Comment: So, two catch blocks one after the other? One more specific NpgsqlException and the other regular Exception?

Comment: exactly, this is the esual approach. You react differently to different exceptions like in [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-how-to-use-multiple-catch-clause/), and in the end you catch everything else, that you haven't thought of

Comment: @Mong Zhu Thank you! I suppose if you post this as an answer, it could be useful for somebody else as well!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend u to change

```
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
       ...
    }
```

to

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ...
    }
```

and see actual type of exception

it can be "PostgresException" https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.PostgresException.html

Comment: I have made these changes and what I get is "Message = No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" and "Source = Npgsql" Shouldn't exceptions of this type be catched by NpgsqlException?

Comment: @niks don't look at the message look at `string typeName = ex.GetType().ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Your try-catch block is outside of the using NpsqlConnection.

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection (connectionString)) {
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand ("loadProjects", connection)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try {
            connection.Open ();

            using (NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader ()) {
                ...
            }

        } catch (NpgsqlException ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why should this make a difference to the approach of @niks ?